# Disable google play store auto update

Tags: google-play-store, android-versions, application-autoupdate

i want to disable google play store auto updates. I am not talking about auto update applications. I don't want to update my google play store version. Please help me.

Comment: @Firelord You can delete your own comments.  And you should flag something if it needs moderator attention, not change the text and hope we see.